# Extract long attribute value with multiple lines

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'd like scrape text from a website tooltip. Its HTML codes are embedded as the value of an attribute `oldtitle`. I tried both css and xpath selectors -- e.g. `//span[@class="spanTip underLine"]/@oldtitle` -- but was not successful. Is it because the attribute value is split into multiple lines? Is there any way to do this using selectors?

```
<tr><td>
<span class="spanTip underLine" style="cursor:default;" data-hasqtip="true" oldtitle="<table class='qtipTable'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>A:</span>1</td>
<td><span class='label'>B:</span>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>C:</span>3</td>
<td><span class='label'>D:</span>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>E:</span></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>F:</span>5</td>
<td><span class='label'>G:</span>6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-5">Item with Tooltip</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What software are you scraping with?

Comment: I'm using scrapy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using Python's BeautifulSoup. To get HTML inside the parameter `oldtitle=`:

```
txt = '''<tr><td>
<span class="spanTip underLine" style="cursor:default;" data-hasqtip="true" oldtitle="<table class='qtipTable'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>A:</span>1</td>
<td><span class='label'>B:</span>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>C:</span>3</td>
<td><span class='label'>D:</span>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>E:</span></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class='label'>F:</span>5</td>
<td><span class='label'>G:</span>6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-5">Item with Tooltip</span>
</td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

inner_soup = BeautifulSoup( soup.select_one('span.spanTip[oldtitle]')['oldtitle'], 'html.parser' )

print(inner_soup)
```

Prints:

```
<table class="qtipTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">A:</span>1</td>
<td><span class="label">B:</span>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">C:</span>3</td>
<td><span class="label">D:</span>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">E:</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">F:</span>5</td>
<td><span class="label">G:</span>6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You can then work with `inner_soup` normally, for example:

```
for tr in inner_soup.select('table tr'):
    print([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')])
```

Prints:

```
['A:1', 'B:2']
['C:3', 'D:4']
['E:']
['F:5', 'G:6']
```

Comment: I should've thought of using BeautifulSoup! It worked!